Jenkins slave on k8s cannot communicate with master node
I have setup a master and slave Jenkins on the same k8s cluster and namespace. Slave pod is from Jenkins-inbound agent. When I triggered a build job, slave pod can be created successfully. But from Jenkins web console it always shows the slave pod as offline

In web console when click into the slave pod, it shows error message like this
The most commonly used option is -webSocket. Run java -jar agent.jar -help for more.

The TCP port is disabled so TCP agents may not be connected. You may still use WebSocket agents. Go to the security configuration screen and change it.

The instance-identity plugin appears to be missing. This would prevent you from connecting a TCP agent. You may still use WebSocket agents. Install it now.

WebSockets are not supported in this Jenkins installation. You may still use TCP agents.

Note: PowerShell users must use curl.exe instead of curl because curl is a default PowerShell cmdlet alias for Invoke-WebRequest.

Agent security setting is setup as below

Any idea why it happens?

I assume you have used kubernetes in cloud section to configure this. in that configuration, did you configure Jenkins tunnel so agents can talk to master node over port 50000.
